# React native, How to not call a value from an API if it is null?

Tags: react-native, mobile, null

In my this [API](https://api.rawg.io/api/games)
I wanted to take the values from the recommended configurations but some values are null, so my application gives me an error:

> null is not an object

Here is my code:

```js
let page1 = this.state.dataSource1.map((val, key) => {
    // if (val.platforms[0].requirements_en.minimum != null) {

    // }
    return (
        {val.platforms[0].requirements_en.recommended ==! null ?
            <Text style={styles.name}>minimal configuration : {val.platforms[0].requirements_en.recommended}</Text>
            :
            <Text>Nothing</Text>
        }
    )
})
```

I wanted to say that if the value is not null, send me the data otherwise a simple text but it does not work...

Comment: Did you mean `!==`?

Comment: It also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got a few issues in your code.

Firstly, you are returning an object, but you don't specify a key.
So you either need to add one, or more likely this is an error and you need to remove the curly braces in your `return`.

Secondly, you have got a typo `==!` instead of `!==`.

Thirdly, about your question you need to check that every element returned by the API exists with the optional chaining operator like so: `val?.platforms[0]?.requirements_en?.recommended`
To expand on this a bit, the optional chaining operator will return `undefined` if the part before the `?.` is `null` or `undefined`.
In your case, sometimes `requirements_en` is null hence why you got your error.

```js
let page1 = this.state.dataSource1.map((val, key) => {
  return val?.platforms[0]?.requirements_en?.recommended ? (
    <Text key={key}>
      minimal configuration: {val.platforms[0].requirements_en.recommended}
    </Text>
  ) : (
    <Text>Nothing</Text>
  )
})
```